# remove resource name and get 404 response with mongoid_slug gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, mongoid

```
namespace :blog do
 resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show], :path => "/"
end
```

If I write:

```
http://localhost:3000/blog/post1
```

and it's working fine. However if I write:

```
http://localhost:3000/blog/invalid_id_fkdkflskdfl
```

I get in log a 200 response:

```
Processing by Blog::PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"invalid_id_fkdkflskdfl"}
  MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database.............................
Completed 200 OK in 60ms
```

In my model:

```
class Post
 include Mongoid::Document
 include Mongoid::Slug
 #slug
 slug :title
 #fields
 field :title
end
```

This is my action show:

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'm using [mongoid_slug](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug) gem

**Why am I not getting a 404 response if this id `invalid_id_fkdkflskdfl`, does not exist?**

**How can I get a 404 response?**

Comment: Maybe in your controller you make a query `Blog.find(params[:id])`, and don't manipulate the render the way you want.

Comment: I have updated my question with more info. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible catch this exception and raise a routing error if you want to render a 404 response. You can do this in your controller, like e.g.:

in your `application_controller.rb` file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  rescue_from Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound, :with => :render_not_found

  def render_not_found
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404", formats: [:html], status: 404, layout: false
  end

  ...

end
```

I your `posts_controller.rb` file:

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id]) || render_not_found
end
```

Thank you to digitalplaywright in this [link](https://github.com/digitalplaywright/mongoid-slug/issues/128)

Regards!